# Found a few small tags which could be burninated

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

While I was browsing the tags I came across a few which look like they could be pruned:

<strike>[bestpactice](/questions/tagged/bestpactice) - presumably created by accident given the typo. 1 Q

[myth-busting](/questions/tagged/myth-busting) - meta-tag? No questions

[old-books](/questions/tagged/old-books) - now off-topic for SO? 4 questions

[oldschool](/questions/tagged/oldschool) - meta? 7 questions</strike>

In addition to old-books there are <strike>[oldfiles](/questions/tagged/oldfiles) (3 Qs)</strike>, <strike>[old-browsers](/questions/tagged/old-browsers) (12 Qs)</strike> <strike>[old-hardware](/questions/tagged/old-hardware) (2 Qs)</strike> and <strike>[old-mac](/questions/tagged/old-mac) (3 Qs)</strike>, which are presumably adequately covered by either [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete) or [outdated](/questions/tagged/outdated)

I also noticed <strike>[not-invented-here](/questions/tagged/not-invented-here) (2 questions)</strike> and [non-technical](/questions/tagged/non-technical) (42 questions), which seem like any question using them would be off-topic on SO/better suited to another SE site (e.g. workplace, or programmers).

Comment: Unused tags are deleted within 24 hours.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that.

Comment: Cleaned up up a couple. If you're going to retag, make sure you address all other issues in the posts as well. And as said by Servy, once there are no further questions tagged, the tag will automatically disappear.

Comment: FWIW: It's no longer possible to migrate questions older than a few months, and in the words of so many people, we should not migrate *crap*.  Most of the questions in [tag:non-technical] are *horrid*.  I would encourage people reviewing those questions to submit close votes as needed and hold off on removing the tag for the time being.

Comment: Please say you flagged these for moderator attention to be closed, as most of the tags indicate that there those questions shouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: I haven't tackled [tag:non-technical] yet, I think a lot were already closed. Many [tag:old-browsers] stood as questions in their own right and already had good tags e.g. [tag:browser-compatibility], so I just un-tagged/edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that all of these tags have so few questions, there is no real need for the team to step in to burninate them.  It would be appropriate to remove the tags from all of the questions that they're tagged with, and then the tags themselves will be deleted automatically after a little while if they remain untagged to any questions.

Just keep in mind that when going through the questions to remove these tags you shouldn't just take off the tag and move on; when editing each question you should fix all of the problems you can find with the question.  If relevant tags are missing, add them, if the question has poor grammar, formatting, spelling, wording, etc. improve that, and so on.  Or, in the case of some of these tags, it's likely that questions tagged with them will need to be closed as offtopic.

Answer (score 3):

In Stack Exchange jargon, *burninating a tag* means removing it from the history of questions. It is done from Stack Exchange staff, and its effect is making it vanish from a question, as it has never been used. It is different from editing it out, as in that case there would be created a revision, and the tag could be re-added by reverting the revision removing it.
It is also different from black-listing a tag, which is avoiding a tag can be entered, even from moderators. Black-listing is doing when none of the question is using the black-listed tag; that can be done by manually editing the questions using it, or burninating the tag before black-listing it.

As burninating is done from Stack Exchange staff, it is normally required when a tag that is not helpful is kept to be used, and there is no way to remove it from new questions because the number of new questions using it is higher than the number of questions from which the tag is removed. This means that burninating a tag is not done when the number of questions using it is very limited, and there are no new questions using it. In such case, editing the tag from the question is what should be done.